# What is an example of an integral domain with a module that is 1-separable but not separable?

Tags: modules, ac.commutative-algebra, abelian-groups

Let R be an integral domain. All modules under discussion are torsion free unital left R-modules.

An R-module is completely decomposable if it is the direct sum of rank 1 submodules.

An R-module is separable if each finite set of its elements is contained in a completely decomposable direct summand.

An R-module is 1-separable if each element is contained in a completely decomposable direct summand.

For torsion free abelian groups, 1-separable implies separable.

```
What is an example of an integral domain R with a module that is 1-separable but not separable?
```

Suppose that the countable direct product of R is separable. If an R-module is 1-separable, is it also separable?